# Is it possible to connect github webpage to SQL database?

Tags: javascript, html, sql-server, github, github-pages

Is it possible to connect github webpage(~~~~.github.io) to database created by SQL server?

I searched this issue in google and someone says it's impossible since github webpage is static.

But I think writing javascript which reads database in html may work. Doesn't it work?

Answer (score 1):

No. Unless you have an API for the database you are trying to use, where in that case, you could use a library like jQuery to send requests to that API.